# Azure - File Share Syncing on Windows 10

Tags: azure, azure-storage, syncservices

I am trying to sync my local folder with Azure's File Share (Storage Account). I downloaded file sync agent but it did not install on my windows 10 machine. Apparently, agent can only be installed on windows server. Could you please suggest how can I proceed?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Azure file sync agent  just can be installed on windows server. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-sync-files-planning) and [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57159)
[image]

So if you want to implement your need, I suggest you can create file share for user with Windows 10 on windows server then sync the folder of the server with Azure file sync.

Besides, if you want  Microsoft to implement the feature, you can vote up the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/35700508-windows-10-support-for-azure-file-sync).